# How to send an HTTP Get request from ServerResource using Restlet apis for Java EE?

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, restlet

I'm new to Restlet apis. So far I've succeeded in sending HTTP Post requests from android device to tomcat server and sending response from the server to the device. Now, I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request from the Tomcat server to another HTTP server. This is my code in the CustomServerResource class :

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(httpGetUrl);
Representation representation = clientResource.get();
```

I get the following error in my console :

```
Dec 6, 2012 7:31:09 PM org.restlet.engine.component.ClientRouter getNext
WARNING: The protocol used by this request is not declared in the list of client     connectors. (HTTP/1.1)
Not Found (404) - The server has not found anything matching the request URI
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:870)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:769)
at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:502)
at com.org.restlet.network.ServerConnection.sendGetRequest(ServerConnection.java:58)
at com.org.restlet.resources.SmsAccessCodeResource.sendAccessCode(SmsAccessCodeResource.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:449)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.post(ServerResource.java:1114)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:533)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doNegotiatedHandle(ServerResource.java:590)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:302)
at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:849)
at org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:513)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:500)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:740)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:155)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:114)
at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:75)
at org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:391)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:500)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:740)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:500)
at org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:740)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:159)
at org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:206)
at org.restlet.engine.ChainHelper.handle(ChainHelper.java:114)
at org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:391)
at org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:491)
at org.restlet.engine.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:74)
at org.restlet.engine.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:153)
at org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1031)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. This is the code I used in CustomServerResource

```
Client client = new Client(new Context(), Protocol.HTTP);
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(httpGetUrl.toString());
clientResource.setNext(client);
clientResource.get();
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it indeed solved your problem :)

Comment: I'll have to wait until tomorrow to do that. :)